# How to make raster layers congruent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have two raster layers. They come with the same cell size (100x100m), the same extent and are projected in the same CRS (`+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`).
My problem is, that they are not exactly congruent, they are off by ca. 50m.
[image]

How can I make them congruent using ArcGIS 10.3 on Windows 10?

Comment: The tools you used to create these rasters, were they in ArcMap? If so then set the _snap raster_ environment setting and all these problems go away.

Comment: No, I created the "not matching" raster using R.

Answer (score 1):

If the location of one raster is wrong, you could try "Export Raster World File" in ArcGIS and then edit the world file in a text editor, adding or subtracting 50m to the X and Y values of the upper left coordinate in the wold file.

Then add the file back to ArcMap and see if it draws in the correct place.

Comment: No, this would be a huge waste of I/O. The [Shift](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/shift.htm) tool exists for this purpose.