# Making raster layers calculated from point feature congruent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, alignment

Raster A and Raster B are both calculated from the same point feature. Raster A results from *Natural Neighbor Interpolation* in the *Spatial Analyst* toolbox. Raster B results from *Point Density* in the *Spatial Analyst* toolbox. However, the rasters are not congruent with each other:

1. Raster B has 2 more columns and two more rows than Raster A
2. Cells of Raster B are shifted relative to cells of Raster A

How to start in order to get congruent rasters from the same point feature? [Shift](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231817/how-to-make-raster-layers-congruent) of one of the rasters is not a solution as the value within a cell should be accurate, i.e. it should represent the area covered by the cell.

[image]

Comment: Shift is the **only** way to alter the origin of a raster. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Recreate raster B and ensure the environment settings are set such that raster B will have the same cell size and raster A and set the snap raster setting is set to raster A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-run Point Density and in the tool environment setting, set the output extent and snap raster to "Raster A":

[image]